# Issue with JSON Parse With Same attribute names in JSON

Tags: apex, integration, json, apexrest, jsongenerator

Here I have doubt How I Can Parse this JSON on apex and Get the data of   "customerPurchaseOrderNumber" numbers, Here problem it is having same name of the json field/atrribute I don't how many it will come when I just put only one Number in CustomerPurchaseordernum it will work How can I parse so many with same attribute name this JSON and retrieve information

```
"customerPurchaseOrderNumbers":[
            {
           "customerPurchaseOrderNumber":"016635",
           "customerPurchaseOrderNumber":"016637",
           "customerPurchaseOrderNumber":"016636"
           "customerPurchaseOrderNumber":"016639"
           }
        ],
```

Apex Class:

```
public class customerPurchaseOrderNumbers{
    public string customerPurchaseOrderNumber{get;set;}
}
 rw = (JsonParserInv)JSON.deserialize(requestString,JsonParserInv.class);

 Ponos=Ponos+';'+rw.customerPurchaseOrderNumbers.customerPurchaseOrderNumber;
```

Comment: If the JSON keys have the same value, the behaviour is unpredictable. Usually, salesforce will only take the last value. To get all values, either this needs to be in form of an array or have key names should be different.

Comment: You have an incorrect JSON here. If you are trying to create an array of values, then your JSON should look like -- `customerPurchaseOrderNumbers[016635, 016637, ...]` at first place.

Comment: Do you have control over how this JSON is generated? If you do, then each of those purchase order key/value pairs should be its own object (customerPurchaseOrderNumbers _is_ a JSON list after all. Little point in using that if everything is going to just be globbed together in a single object)

Comment: No I don't have control it is coming from other system

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object